# Chat application for one-on-one chat in PHP

Tags: chat

I am looking for a chat application written in PHP, allowing a group of people in an office to interact with each other.

It can be one to one or may be a group chat application for my PHP based web application.

I do not want to use any third party website for receiving chat, just want everything (receiver end and sender end ) on my web based application.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931

Comment: https://www.cometchat.com/

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649771/Chat-Application-in-PHP

Comment: http://www.phpfreechat.net/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/

Comment: Did you even bother looking for yourself? I've added links I assume cover your requirements.